# My program won't run due to error with the main method/java class file exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to figure out the selection sort algorithm and understand it by printing out each line, but when I run it, the console won't even pop up. I know my error has to do something with the main class exception not found and the main string args method but I don't know how to fix it to see the output.

```
package sort;


public class Sorting {
    private int[] a = new int[]{ 11, 9, 17, 5, 12 }; 



    public Sorting(int[]a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public void sortInSpace(int[]a) {
        for(int startOfUnsorted = 0; startOfUnsorted<a.length; startOfUnsorted++) {
            int smallestInUnsorted = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            System.out.println(smallestInUnsorted);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the command you execute to start the program, as well as the exact error.

Comment: Hi, I wonder how are you running the program? Perhaps put a print statement in `main` to see if it executes.

Comment: Share your error if you have one. Also, your `main` method is empty, so I wouldn't expect anything to happen.

Comment: `main` is the entry point to your program. If if it is empty, nothing will happen. You need to add code to `main` to create a `Sorting` object then call its `sortInSpace` function.

Comment: when I put System.out.println("Hi"); in the main method, it prints, but why won't my SortinSpace method print ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function in Sorting is empty so it won't print anything if you try to run that class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Instead I would do the following -

```
public class Sorting {
private int[] a; 

public Sorting(int[]a) {
    this.a = a;
} 
public void sortInSpace(int[]a) {
for(int startOfUnsorted = 0; startOfUnsorted<a.length; startOfUnsorted++) 
{
        int smallestInUnsorted = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println(smallestInUnsorted);

    }
}
}
```

**Create another class** which will *initiate* an object type of Sorting and use the object to call the method.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
       int[] a = new int[]{ 11, 9, 17, 5, 12 }; 
       Sorting sortObj = new Sorting(a);
       sortObj.sortInSpace(a);

}
```

Output -

```
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
2147483647
```